# Faster Alternative to Unix Grep

Tags: unix, grep

I'm trying to do the following

```
$ grep ">" file.fasta > output.txt
```

But it is taking so long when the input fasta file is large.

The input file looks like this:

```
>seq1
ATCGGTTA
>seq2
ATGGGGGG
```

Is there a faster alternative?

Comment: It probably will not make a big difference in the I/O-dominated big scheme of things, but you could try to anchor the match to the first character of each line, if that is what you want.

Comment: @Thilo That's what came to my mind, too, but the difference is only about 10% for me.

Comment: Build a state machine-based recogniser ? (will need about 4 states)

Answer (score 4):

Use time command with all these

```
$> time grep ">" file.fasta > output.txt

$> time egrep ">" file.fasta > output.txt

$> time awk  '/^>/{print $0}' file.fasta > output.txt -- If ">' is first letter
```

If you see the output..they are almost the same .

In my opinion ,if the data is in **columnar format**, then  use **awk** to search.

Answer (score 4):

Hand-built state machine. If you only want '>' to be accepted at the beginning of the line, you'll need one more state. If you need to recognise '\r' too, you will need a few more states.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int state,ch;

for(state=0; (ch=getc(stdin)) != EOF;   ) {
        switch(state) {
        case 0: /* start */
                if (ch == '>') state = 1;
                else break;
        case 1: /* echo */
                fputc(ch,stdout);
                if (ch == '\n') state = 0;
                break;
                }
        }
if (state==1) fputc('\n',stdout);
return 0;
}
```

If you want *real* speed, you could replace the fgetc() and fputc() by their macro equivalents getc() and putc(). (but I think trivial programs like this will be I/O bound anyway)

Answer (score 3):

For big files, the fastest possible `grep` can be accomplished with [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). An example using `parallel` and `grep` can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__parallel_grep).

For your purposes, you may like to try:

```
cat file.fasta | parallel -j 4 --pipe --block 10M grep "^\>" > output.txt
```

The above will use four cores, and parse 10 MB blocks to `grep`. The block-size is optional, but I find using a 10 MB block-size quite a bit faster on my system. YRMV.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Ack is a good alternative to grep to find string/regex in code :

http://beyondgrep.com/